# Clear adjacent cell content based on data validation drop down list value

Tags: vba, excel

Please can you help me to clear content next to target column with data validation value "No follow up" and "Follow up completed". The following code helps me to set up next follow up date in the cells next to target value column H by choosing a data validation option (Case 1, case 5, case 7). Basically I would like to add to this code a couple of more option from my data validation drop down list "No follow up" and "Follow up completed" and make to these two option clear the content into next cell.

I hope it's clear my question related this two new option I would like operating in this code.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Column <> Columns("H").Column Then Exit Sub
 Select Case Target.Value2
     Case 1, 5, 7: Target.Offset(0, 1).value = NextWorkday(Date,Target.Value2)
 End Select

 End Sub

 Function NextWorkday(dtDate As Date, lngDaysToAdd As Long)
    NextWorkday = dtDate + lngDaysToAdd
    Select Case Weekday(NextWorkday, vbMonday)
        Case 6: NextWorkday = NextWorkday + 2
        Case 7: NextWorkday = NextWorkday + 1
    End Select
 End Function
```

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)                             If Target.Column <> Columns("H").Column Then Exit Sub                   Select Case Target.Value2                                                                     Case 1, 5, 7: Target.Offset(0, 1).value = NextWorkday(Date,Target.Value2) End Select.                                                                                                End Sub

Comment: it's not clear what you want ?  Are you getting any errors with this code ? Are you looking to do more ?

Comment: Basically I would like to add to this code (that works alright)a couple of more option from my data validation drop down list "No follow up" and "Follow up completed" and make to these two option clear the content into next cell.

Comment: Do you think is it still unclear?

Comment: Just add another `Case` to your Worksheet_Change `Select` block.

Comment: I have tried to add it but it doesn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: Would like please to show me how? Thanks

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column <> Columns("H").Column Then Exit Sub
  Select Case Target.Value2
    Case 1, 3, 7: Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = NextWorkday(Date, Target.Value2)
    Case "No Follow up": Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    Case "Follow up completed": Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
  End Select
End Sub